# Android SharedPreferences not changing

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferenceactivity

So I am learning about [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) within Android.

I thought I would quickly try and mock up something simple. When the user selects a particular option from a list of options (3 options in this case) - the layout file will change accordingly. However, it always assumes the default value supplied, hence never changes the layout when another option is selected - so when another option is selected, it is recorded fine, but the layout doesn't change, this leads me to believe that there is perhaps a problem occurring when getting the preferences in the first place, I was wondering if someone could take a quick look and spot something obvious, or not so obvious with their experience/wisdom - here is the code:

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.preferenceslayout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
    implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        loadPreferences();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.preferences:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                     AppPreferences.class));
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void loadPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().
            getSharedPreferences("mode", MODE_PRIVATE);
        int layoutPref = prefs.getInt("mode", 10);
        switch(layoutPref) {
        case 10:
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            break;
        case 20:
            setContentView(R.layout.second_layout);
            break;
        case 30:
            setContentView(R.layout.third_layout);
            break;
        }
        prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(MainActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences arg0, String arg1) {
        loadPreferences();      
    }
}
```

preference.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <ListPreference
        android:key="mode"
        android:title="@string/mode"
        android:defaultValue="1"
        android:summary="@string/summary"
        android:entries="@array/listArray"
        android:entryValues="@array/listValues" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

AppPreferences.xml:

```
package com.example.preferenceslayout;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class AppPreferences extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference);
    }
}
```

main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/preferences"
        android:title="Preferences" />
</menu>
```

PreferencesLayoutManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.preferenceslayout"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.preferenceslayout.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.preferenceslayout.AppPreferences">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".AppPreferences" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

array.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="listArray">
        <item>10</item>
        <item>20</item>
        <item>30</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="listValues">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: I noticed you don't have a constant or an R string for the name of your preferences file.  I like to use the app_name so I can easily re-use the preferences class with any app.    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.app_name), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: Even better use default shared preferences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never *write* to your preferences. You need a `prefs.putInt("mode", some_int);` somewhere. Also your listener serves no purpose whatsoever - drop it.

You are writing to the *default shared preferences* cause preferences screens write there. The "mode" is just the key - there is one key in the default shared preferences and one in your preference file (named "mode_something.xml") - but you write the one (automatically via the preferences screen) and you read the other (which is never set)

Comment: There is a PreferenceActiviy with a ListPreference where the "mode" gets set. Well, the listener can be really dropped, yes :-)

Comment: @donfuxx: I thought you were the OP :D - are you sure it's set in the Preference activity he's posted ? ;)

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D, I printed it and it is definitely set.

Comment: @user2405469: using `getDefaultSharedPreferences()` ?

Comment: OH GOSH, wait... I did this: SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("mode", MODE_PRIVATE);
  Map<String, ?> keys = prefs.getAll();        
  
  for(Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : keys.entrySet()) {
   Log.d("value", entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue().toString());
  }                                                                    basically...even though the second option is set, it is saying that the value is zero...when it should be twenty, you are right! @Mr_and_Mrs_D

Comment: debugging it...stepping over the value, it is 0 as well, so you are right, it hasn't been written...I'll write it.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D, ahhhh thank you! I didn't know that by default it would go there, although I should've guessed it...insightful thank you!

Comment: @user2405469: Stop thanking me just push the button ;)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't look too deep into your code, but after a quick overview the following catched my attention:

you are setting this in your ListPreference in your preference.xml

```
android:entries="@array/listArray"
android:entryValues="@array/listValues"
```

but in your array.xml you have 3 items in your entries string-array and just 2 items in your listValues string-array

```
<string-array name="listArray">
    <item>10</item>
    <item>20</item>
    <item>30</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="listValues">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
</string-array>
```

You should **add a third item** to your listValues string-array

BTW: you should consider renaming "listArray" so that it is more clear that it holds the Entries of your list. So maybe call it "listEntries". (remember to also change reference to `android:entries="@array/listEntries"` then) In general the entries are what the user actually sees, the values is what android uses. So for example your string array could look something like:

```
<string-array name="listEntries">
    <item>one apple</item>
    <item>two apples</item>
    <item>three apples</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="listValues">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: Thank you @donfuxx - this really helps, it is more understandable this way, didn't notice the missing item.

Answer (score 1):

*onSharedPreferenceChanged* will be called every time you change your preferences, so don't instantiate a new *SharedPreferences* object each time you change a preference, what you have to do is:

First, make *SharedPreferences* a class attribute, so you can access to a preference everywhere in your Activity:

```
private SharedPreferences prefs;
```

Now, inside *onCreate()* call:

```
prefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
```

And finally, your *loadPreferences()* method should look like this:

```
public void loadPreferences() {

    int layoutPref = prefs.getInt("mode", 10);
    switch(layoutPref) {
    case 10:
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        break;
    case 20:
        setContentView(R.layout.second_layout);
        break;
    case 30:
        setContentView(R.layout.third_layout);
        break;
    }

}
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thank you rick really helps, really appreciate it :)

Comment: Happy to hear that!! if was usefull for you could you mark this answer as accepted or vote up? Thank you :)