# Android - Is it bad practice to have multiple Shared Preferences?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have an app making use of `SharedPreferences`. One just stores app version to check against update for a changelog, the other contains some layout info that `clear()` gets called on as the user chooses. I finally managed to get a `PreferenceFragment` working and noticed a trend, so I thought I might ask this now before i go preference crazy (though I think I have enough).

I've done my best to search and see no specific mention of a problem, only that it's possible to have multiples.

I'm a little concerned about `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()` grabbing the wrong pref, but I might simply be misunderstanding the usage.

The only relevant code i could think of from my activity:

```
SharedPreferences storedVer = getSharedPreferences(VER_NUM, 0);
SharedPreferences savedLayout = getSharedPreferences(LAYOUT_SAVE, 0);
```

Comment: Each named sharedPreference creates a new XML file, it is not a bad practise if you think it helps you keep data more organized and easier to find.

Comment: Ah, thanks for confirming. Should i be concerned about what `.getDefaultSharedPreferences()` returns?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is not bad practice at all. I think it is the opposite. I think different behaviours should use different `sharedPreference` files.

`.getDefaultSharedPreferences()` uses the default `com.company.packagename.xml` file. And the others create their own files.

The followings advantages of using multiple `sharedPreference's` come up in my mind.

- When you use BackupManager, you can provide which `sharedPreference` files to backup and restore.
- When the user logout, you can delete `sharedPreference` file with that users private values in it. You may not want to delete some other.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of `.getDefaultSharedPreferences()`, I was a bit confused what was going on when that was called.

Answer (score 10):

From my experience with the `SharedPreferences` I have noticed the following:

**1)** Always use try to make your `SharedPreference` name and Attributes name unique all over the device.

**2)** Do not use the name of your `SharedPreference` like "myPreference", "preference", "appPreference"...etc. Use your `PackageName` as a unique identifier for the `SharedPreference` name.

Example:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(Context.getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

**3)** Use also a unique Keys for your attributes by concatenating the attribute name with the package name.

Example:

```
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
boolean isAdminKey = Context.getPackageName()+"admin";
editor.putString(isAdminKey , "value");
editor.commit();
```

**4)** No problem with editing multiple Keys values with one `commit()`.

**5)** Use `MODE_PRIVATE` when you create your preferences to prevent other applications from reading your `SharedPreferences`. See step 2 for example

**6)** Do not rely on the `SharedPreferences` 100% because it will be cleared if the user pressed `Clear Data` button from the App info screen. Otherwise, create file in the `ExternalDirectory()` or send your info to a server.

Comment: I think creating files in external directory directly is bad practice.  When you do that, you mass up users file system and sd card. I have tens of folders from various applications. I use the provided place in external file system. And it is also deleted when user select clear data.

Comment: Besides, when user wants to clear data, the data should be cleared. There is no point to stop it.

Comment: I don`t prefer this, but a lot of famous apps do this like `watsapp` and `viber`. This way will allow you to keep your data away from any `Clear data` action and `Uninstall` action :) @tasomaniac

Comment: Great breakdown, it seems wise to follow your suggestions. I picked an answer but have an upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but I would say *do not use multiple preferences*. Stick with `getDefaultSharedPreferences`. I have seen many fail to keep track of the names of the saved preferences. In general it makes the code more complicated in just the wrong way (the compiler can't help you manage your names). Moreover shared preferences are for a handful of small values - use the Filesystem for big things and a database for a lot of data.

I have seen the named shared preferences be used a lot and I believe this is an unfortunate trend spread by `copyPaste()`.

Finally, your preference activities write to the default shared preferences - I have recently answered a question where this was the issue - would be completely avoided if default preferences were used. See: [Android SharedPreferences not changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713087/android-sharedpreferences-not-changing/21716160#21716160)

You might consider wrapping the default shared preferences methods to make them even less verbose as I've done [here](https://github.com/Utumno/AndroidHelpers/blob/master/src/gr/uoa/di/android/helpers/AccessPreferences.java)

Comment: Interesting point, @Mr_and_Mrs_D. I can see where minimizing my number of shared prefs would make sense and only add more if I truly need them, but like I say one of the prefs gets a `clear()`called as often as the user chooses and I don't have the knowledge yet of a better way to do it. So if I am using that pref for everything I believe it would lose its contents quite often. I've considered filesystem and database options, but i think it's just a little outside the scope of my app (at least for now).

Comment: @ziondreamt: consider  [editor.remove("key")](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#remove(java.lang.String))