# Is it a good idea to create a new SharedPreferences object everyday the app is used?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I've read other topics, and it says that multiple shared preferences are a good thing ([Android - Is it bad practice to have multiple Shared Preferences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21847872/android-is-it-bad-practice-to-have-multiple-shared-preferences))
, however one shouldn't store a lot of data using prefs. However what is meant by "a lot of data"? Every new day the app is ran, it creates a new key-value pair with the current date as the key... Is this a good idea or should I switch to SQLite?

```
class TimeAndMoneyForASpecificDay (val context: Context) {

    private fun obtainDate(): String{ 
        val df = SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy")
        return df.format(Date())
    }

    fun saveTimeWorkedAndMoneyEarned(timeWorked: Float, moneyEarned: Float) {

        val current = obtainDate() 

        val time = context.getSharedPreferences("time", 0) // ??
        val money = context.getSharedPreferences("money",0)

        val timeEditor = time.edit()
        val moneyEditor = money.edit()


        timeEditor.putFloat(current, timeWorked) 
        moneyEditor.putFloat(current, moneyEarned)

        timeEditor.apply()
        moneyEditor.apply()


    }
}
```

Comment: Do you only keep a certain number of days in total, or do you expect someone to still be using your app in 4 years time? This is really a design choice. Also, what happens when someone does a "clear cache" request? An SQLite DB would be removed too BTW in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As @Tigger mentioned this is a design choice, but if you think that user may use your app you a couple of years it's not a bad idea to delete old info cause a lot of keys in shared preferences makes it slow to read/update and if you chose to use shared preferences make sure you delete some old keys. Shared preferences are simple XM files so it goes without saying that a lot of keys makes them slow.
you can also check out my repo which supports expiry and arguments for key (e.g. your date) [EasyPrefs](https://github.com/amin-amini/EasyPrefs)